# Why does the Applet not produce output in the font I set?

Tags: java, fonts, applet

I made an applet wherein I assigned the font properties to a **Font** class object **f** in the **Applet** class. In the    **paint()** method I used the **setFont()** method to set the font properties of the current Graphics object to that of **'f'**. But the **drawString()** method seems to display in the default font (maybe **Arial**) and not the font I set (though the **font size**, **font style** and **colour** was what I set). This is supposed to work according to the book I followed but isn't. Please find me the flaws in my code. Thanks.

```
/*Applet to use set Font*/

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class UsingFont extends Applet {

    Font f=new Font("Algerian",Font.BOLD,30);

    @Override
    public void init() {}

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(f);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawString("ALGERIAN FONT",20,15);
    }//paint
}//class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Algerian doesnt exist in your system so it substitutes the closest or default

try to see which fonts are available in your system:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] gf=ge.getAllFonts();
String[] gfn=ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

Comment: Yes you are right. **Algerian** doesn't exist in my system. I used **Bradley Hand ITC** instead which I made sure was in my system and it's working. Thanks for helping out this noob.